# Output BLOB video

Tags: php, video, blob

have been able to output images from BLOB,

however I am now wanting to print out a MOV video which is saved in BLOB as well.

The video type is MOV

I am Using PHP but not sure how to print out the video.

Comment: http://us.php.net/echo or http://us.php.net/print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on onteria's reply. If your DB engine has large object (LOB) functionality, you'll additionally want to read:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select contenttype, imagedata from images where id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

header("Content-Type: $type");
fpassthru($lob);
?>
```

This will avoid fetching the entire large object into memory in one go.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to send the proper headers for Content-Type, then just echo out the data:

```
header("Content-Type: video/quicktime");
echo $blob_data;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the exact same as an image, you would just echo the contents, the only time you need to manage the content that is being sent is when your doing streaming where there are several requests asking for specific parts of the data.

```
echo $blob; //is your man
```